# Images doesn't work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, addition

I already did search on youtube and here and probably it is silly question but I couldn't find how to make it work.

Question is when I add pictures in my eclipse file they look like;

[image]

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("view.jpg"));
    label1 = new JLabel(image1);
    add(label1);

    image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("view1.jpg"));
    label1 = new JLabel(image2);
    add(label2);    // here my code
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try: `.getResource("Image/Images/view.jpg")`?

Comment: I tried it after you but it doesn't work :( but Don't I need see in Image file like a picture? They look like notepad writing

Comment: I fix it LOL I put the picture only in file and it works now. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

My got a use method to set icon for label, you can refer

```
private void loadAvartar(JLabel lbl, String path){
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(100, 100, 50));
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
    } catch (IOException | java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        lbl.setText("Failed");
    }

}
```

Comment: I fix it LOL I put the picture only in file and it works now. Thank you

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.